# renderInContext creating memory that is not promptly released

Tags: iphone, memory, core-graphics, instruments

While debugging in instruments using 'ObjectAlloc' I'm noticing 7megs of memory being allocated for the renderInContext call, but it never is released. When I comment out the renderInContext call this doesn't happen, and future renderInContext calls does not continue to increase the memory allotment.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contentHolder.bounds.size);
[contentHolder.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Is there a way to force this memory to be released?

Comment: It may be a cache owned by the layer. What happens if/when you release the layer?

Comment: I am also facing same problem. does anyone got why it is doing memory leak?

Comment: My problem went away when I started compiling for 4.2

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to release the renderInContext memory. Simply run the method calling renderInContext on Main Thread and that will release the allocated memory automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure why Apple doesn't fix this after not allow us to use UIGetScreenImage which is like 10x faster.  If we do a capture of an Retina iPad, the UI would lag because of renderInContext blocking the Main thread.  renderInContext is very very slow as i've seen in instruments.

Comment: Also in addition to renderInContext having memory issues running on non-main thread, it also does not play well on some iOS 6 views such as the MKMap Views or any view using OpenGL ES (it will crash not capturing maps in main thread).  It crashes deep within the video subsystems.