# how to release memory after renderInContext with ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, release

My app take a screenshot about my view. The code works but the profile/allocations tool shows that memory isn't released the context. Here is some code about this:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];   //allocations tool shows 49.6% alert here!


UIImage *wallpaper = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I tried to use autorelease{} but nothing works...
So my app memory usage is getting higher and higher after this action, I don't know how to release this context.
I'm using ARC.

Comment: Where is that code?  Inside a `[UIView drawRect:]` or not?

Comment: The code I mentioned is the above code. It generates the screenshot, no problem with it!

Comment: I'll repeat the question then: Is it inside a `[UIView drawRect:]` method or not?

Comment: not! it's not inside of this

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970627/releasing-renderincontext-result-within-a-loop

Comment: Or this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785401/renderincontext-creating-memory-that-is-not-promptly-released

Comment: I have seen this question before. It's seemed a good answer (however it's not ARC), but nothing worked for me about it.

Comment: I can't understand if I use the autorelease {} for the above code, than why those staffs isn't released from the memory?!?!

Comment: the closest question to my one is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646833/renderincontext-taxes-app-memory

Comment: This has nothing to do with `autorelease`. autorelease is _not_ a method for freeing memory, it is a method for _preventing_ premature deallocation. read the links @trojanfoe posted.